# Multiple Monitors Start Menu

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

I've got 3 monitors and I'm running Windows XP. I was wondering if its possible to change the monitor which contains the Start menu.

I've downloaded UltraMon thinking that it would do the trick, but there was no luck there.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Right-click the monitor in the Display Properties --> Settings Tab and select "Primary."

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just move the taskbar?  Make sure it's unlocked of course.

Answer (score 2):

On the Display settings tab (Right click the desktop and go to Dislpay, the last tab) You'll see 3 monitors there with numbers.

-First you can click on the Identify monitors button, this will let you know with big numbers on the monitor which one it is.

-Then select the one that you want to be the primary, there's a checkbox that says This is my main monitor. Check it there and it will make it the primary, which means where the taskbar is.

If this doesn't work, usually the video card drivers have some sort of settings.

-Click on that same tab on the Advanced Setting, there you'll see a tab with something like NVdia or ATI or whoever is the card manufacturer.

-Once there look for the settings on the monitors and it should be something similar, some checkbox that says that you want that monitor as your default one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to change which monitor XP thinks is number one? Would that change which monitor the start menu appeared on?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this myself. Right click the taskbar and make sure that it's not locked as described by "JackM". Then click and drag the taskbar to the middle monitor.